# How to authenticate user via REST using email and password with Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a very simple desire: to authenticate (log in) user over REST. I need to use email and password.

settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'modeltranslation',
    'corsheaders',
    'django_s3_storage',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_auth',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account'
]

'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
),

ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True   
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
 "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
 "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend",
)
```

urls.py:

```
re_path(r'^rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
```

When I do:

```
curl \
  -X POST \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{"email": "admin@test.com", "password": "zyzzyx' \
  http://localhost:8000/rest-auth/login/
```

The error message is: Unable to log in with provided credentials.

EDIT:

I'm using custom user model:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='%(class)s_company')
    role = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        choices=ROLE_CHOICES,
        default='admin',
    )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)
        db_table = "custom_user"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

User = get_user_model()
```

In settings.py:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapps.CustomUser'
```

Comment: Your `curl` request looks fine. Probably either the credential is wrong or the `login controller` is having the problem.

Comment: The credentials are correct. I can log into Django admin with that password and username admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up storing email address in the username field as well.

Answer (score 1):

In order to token authenticate using built in methods of `django_rest_framwork`, you should call `obtain_auth_token` method.

So, your urls.py will look something like

```
from django.urls import path
from rest_framework.authtoken.views import obtain_auth_token  # <-- Here
from myapi.core import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('rest-auth/', obtain_auth_token, name='api_token_auth'),  # <-- And here
]
```

Refer [this tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/11/22/how-to-implement-token-authentication-using-django-rest-framework.html) for more details.

**Update 1**

Looks like you have not properly configured `rest_auth`, that is why your login is failing. You should set `REST_SESSION_LOGIN` to `True` for session authentication. And if you need token authentication, set `REST_USE_JWT` to `True`. Refer [this documentation](https://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html) for all available configurations.

Comment: I think I could cope with SessionAuthentication, not token.

Comment: Can you share your settings for `rest_auth`? I'm seeing the package is processing `django_login` based on the settings. You can see the source [here](https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/blob/master/rest_auth/views.py)

Comment: I think all the settings I have at the moment relating the rest_auth is included in the  original question, if I'm following you. Am I missing something?

Comment: You shoud set `REST_SESSION_LOGIN` to `True` for session authentication.

Comment: Default value for REST_SESSION_LOGIN is True.